# Difference in equations of LASER and plane monochromatic wave

Tags: optics, laser

I was asked in an interview to write the equation of a plane monochromatic wave. I wrote it as:

$$ E = E_0 \exp(i(k.x - wt)) $$

Now, they asked me to differentiate between this and light LASER.
Although I know the basics of both this seemed difficult as the main properties of LASER are directionality, monochromaticity, and coherence. The plane wave equation seemed to suggest all of that. The interviewer hinted to me that the answer is related to temporal coherence but I couldn't figure out why it would not be coherent. Can one explain how?

Comment: The real difference is quantum statistics, which is non-classical. I am not sure that's what they were asking. One can make a laser-like near-monochromatic light source by filtering light from thermal or other non-coherent sources (e.g. to make a hologram), but the resulting intensity would be extremely low. A laser is far superior as a monochromatic and spatially coherent light source.

Comment: In addition,- usually laser beam basic $TEM_{00}$ mode has Gaussian profile, so in this case laser light intensity is described by equation : $$I \! \left( r \right) = I_0 \exp{\left( \frac{-2 r^2}{w \left( \! z \right)^2} \right)}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your interviewer knows exactly what they meant, but I suspect they might mean that lasers remain coherent only for times of the order of $100\mathrm{ns}$ to $1\mu\textrm{s}$. This means the equation is really something like:

$$ E(x,t) = E_0 \exp(i(kx - \omega t + \phi(t))) $$

where $\phi(t)$ is a phase offset that varies randomly on a timescale of $100\mathrm{ns}$ to $1\mu\textrm{s}$.

So at any time $t$ the light from the laser remains coherent everywhere in space i.e. the phase varies sinusoidally with distance. That's why lasers produce such good interference patterns. But if we picked a point in space and looked at the variation with time we'd find the phase varied sinusoidally only for short periods and experienced random jumps every now and then.

Usually for lasers we refer to a [coherence length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length), which is just $c$ times the coherence time. Typically this is around $100\textrm{m}$ though it depends on the type of laser and can vary widely.